# Вопрос по Java. Когда нет оператора new,

Tags: java, android

Читаю литературу по Java. Параллельно начал читать документацию [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/)

Из книги знаю что можно создавать **экземпляр класса с помощью оператора new** затем используя ссылочную переменную вызывать методы этого класса. 
Способность понимать код "на лету" пока на минимуме. **Поэтому все новое - пугает.**

На [Девелопере](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) есть такой код: `MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();`. Хочу понять что здесь происходит? Почему нет оператора new и то что стоит за знаком "=" - это метод этого класса? Прошу объяснять как можно проще, чтобы я не запутался.

Спасибо.

Comment: Значит вызов new в том или ином виде спрятан внутри getMenuInflater, элементарно же

Comment: или `getMenuInflater` возвращает ссылку на существующий объект

Comment: `getMenuInflater();` в данном случае можно читать как `this.getMenuInflater();`. Здесь это не создание нового объекта, а обычный вызов метода.

Answer (score 4):

потому что в таком методе может стоять например проверка на то что объект уже существует и возвращает его, либо создает новый объект и его возращает

```
public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
    return new MenuInflater(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Привет.
Давай все разберем по порядку.
Ты в качестве пример привел часть кода `MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();`

`MenuInflater` - это [Класс](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29#.D0.9A.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.81.D1.8B_.D0.B2_.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8B.D0.BA.D0.B5_Java) объекта
дальше идет `inflater` - это переменная, которая хранит ссылку на [объект](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

В Java программе могут быть несколько переменных, которые могут ссылаться на один и тот же объект. Если переменной не присвоить ссылку на объект она cодержит по умолчанию значение `null`, что означает что данная переменная ни на что не ссылается.

За ним следует оператор `=` это простой оператор присваивания, он присваивает значение с правой стороны в левую. В данном случае у нас присваивается ссылка на объект из правой части в левую.

Ну вот добрались до самого главного.
В случае с оператором `new` он вызывает у класса Конструктор и создает в памяти новый объект. В результате на выход он передает ссылку на этот объект. А оператор `=` присваивает эту ссылку переменной `inflater`.

В вашем случае вызывается функция которая передает ссылку на объект.
Внутри этой функции может создаваться новый объект или также вызываться другая функция которая передаст этот ссылку.

Вам следует больше почитать про ООП в Java и объекты что бы лучше разобраться с этим.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, непонятность возникает из за того, что метод вызывается, а у какого объекта -- непонятно. В случае с `MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();` метод `getMenuInflater()` находится в том же классе, что и этот код. Особенно это непонятно из за того, что в том классе который мы создаем его не видно. Но нужно понимать, что класс, который мы создаем, наледуется от другого, который является частью андроида(сдк). [Здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getMenuInflater()) видно, что это метод класса `Activity` от которого мы и наследуемся.

Answer (score 0):

`getMenuInflater()` - либо метод того же класса, либо публичный статический метод какого-то иного утилитарного класса. Этот метод вызывает new и возвращает экземпляр класса. Возможно - другого класса, имплементирующего MenuInflater. Например - наследника. Какого-нибудь MySuperModifiedenuInflater. 
Подробнее стоит почитать о паттерне (шаблоне) проектирования Фабрика (Factor y Method).

Answer (score 0):

Вставлю свои пять коппек и покажу юзеру на пальцах.

```
class A {

    String getMegaString() {
        return "mega string!!";
    }
}

class B extends A {

    void myMethod() {
        String got = this.getMegaString();
    }
}
```

здесь магическое слово this можно опустить. Будет тож самое. Простой вызов метода супер класса. Советую почитать какую нибудь книжку по основам Явы. таких уйма. [Например вот](http://oz.by/books/more1017877.html) одна из простейших